# Location of Magento API password

Tags: magento-1.9, api, password-recovery

Can anyone tell me where this is set?
I need to check it's value.

I've looked in admin console and in app/etc/config.xml and app/etc/local.xml

Comment: How you added the password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords for both SOAP and REST APIs are stored in the Database and are encrypted of course (MD5 + SALT).

```
SELECT *
FROM `api_user`
```

You may reset API password(API-Key) for any API-User in Backend under

```
System->Web Services->SOAP/XML-RPC - Users
```

(This requires magento admin permissions)

Comment: Thanks. Found it!! It doesn't display the original password, but you change password here if you know the original. But this helped me confirm what the password is. thanks

Answer (score -1):

The API password is set via administration. You need to look under the System's menu.